# Grails Release Inexplicably Fails to Publish to Nexus

Tags: maven, grails, nexus, publishing

**Background:** I'm trying to migrate projects to use our new, upgraded nexus instance instead of the old one. Gradle projects and Maven projects went smoothly, but not so with Grails projects.

**Problem:** Releases, and releases alone fail to publish to the new nexus. Snapshot publishing works just fine. Both snapshots and release publishing worked fine in the old nexus, and the Maven and Gradle projects I moved over that use the same user credentials work just fine as well.

The error is as follows

> POM generated: /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/xml-data/build-dir/CS-AREL-JOB1/target/pom.xml.
>
> [deploy] Deploying to https://nexus.mydomain.com/repository/maven-releases/
>
> [deploy] Uploading: com/mydomain/myproject-admin/1.11.9/myproject-admin-1.11.9.war to repository atlassian_nexus_releases at https://nexus.mydomain.com/repository/maven-releases/
>
> [deploy] Transferring 44484K from atlassian_nexus_releases
>
> [deploy] Error writing to server
>
> [deploy] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
>
> [deploy]  Diagnosis:
>
> [deploy]
>
> [deploy] Error deploying artifact 'com.mydomain:myproject-admin:war': Error deploying artifact: Error transferring file
>
> [deploy] Error writing to server

**What I need are some ideas on where to look, 'cause all the common checks seem to not be the issue.** The user credentials are correct and work for the gradle and maven projects. The URL is correct and works for the gradle and maven projects. The build hasn't changed between old nexus and new nexus usage, so I assume the build is still correctly producing release artifacts and not snapshot artifacts. What else could be the problem?

**Configuration:**

*grails.settings.groovy*

```
grails.project.dependency.authentication = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "https://nexus.mydomain.com/repository/maven-public/"
    }
    credentials {
        id = "atlassian_nexus"
        username = "dev_read_user"
        password = "****"
    }
}
grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "https://nexus.mydomain.com/repository/maven-public/"
    }
    credentials {
        realm = "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
        host = "atlassian.mydomain.com"
        username = "dev_read_user"
        password = "****"
    }
}
grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    localRepository = "~/.m2/"
    remoteRepository(id: "atlassian_nexus_snapshots", url: 'https://nexus.mydomain.com/repository/maven-snapshots/'){
        authentication(username: 'nexus_user', password: '****')
    }
    remoteRepository(id: "atlassian_nexus_releases", url: 'https://nexus.mydomain.com/repository/maven-releases/'){
        authentication(username: 'nexus_user', password: '****')
    }
}
```

The above file has seen the most changes during the migration, so I believe it to be the most likely culprit, though it may also be possible that some configuration of nexus itself could be an issue?

*bamboo-build-release.sh*

```
echo 'Making and commiting release version...';
JAVA_HOME=$bamboo_jdk_1_8 \
./grailsw version-update x.x.x --non-interactive;
git commit -m 'Increment version to release' -- application.properties;

echo 'Creating and pushing tag...';
grep app.version application.properties | cut -d"=" -f2 | xargs -I 
version git tag -a version -m "Tag Release";
git push $GIT_URL --tags;

echo 'Building RELEASE war and publishing to Nexus...';
JAVA_HOME=$bamboo_jdk_1_8 \
./grailsw prod maven-deploy --repository=atlassian_nexus_releases -- non-interactive -verbose;

echo 'Incrementing to next snapshot...';
JAVA_HOME=$bamboo_jdk_1_8 \
./grailsw version-update p s --non-interactive;

echo 'Committing and pushing version changes...';
git commit -m 'Increment version to next snapshot' --application.properties;
git push $GIT_URL $GIT_BRANCH;

echo 'Completed bamboo-build-release.sh';
```

The only thing I changed in the above build file is to add '-verbose' so I could get a little more information as to why it was failing. As seen above, it didn't provide much more detail on why the publish failed.

I verified that the generated pom had the correct, non-snapshot version specified:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject-admin</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.11.9</version>
  <name>myproject-admin</name>
</project>
```

Please advise what ideas on what I could be looking for that's causing the problem.

Comment: Is there already a version 1.11.9 on the repository?  If so, it will fail to upload.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there are actually NO versions in the release repo because it's a brand new repo. There's a 1.11.9-SNAPSHOT in the snapshots repo, but as noted in grails.settings.groovy, they are two different URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm still not sure why it consistently failed for releases and worked for snapshots, the following solution for intermittent ivy-to-nexus-failures worked for me: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/218101688-Ivy-deploy-fails-intermittently-with-java-io-IOException-Error-writing-to-server-

I ended up adding the following dependencies in the BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
dependencies{
    build 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.7'
    build 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    build 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1'

    // other dependencies...
}
```